# Android & Google Maps - How to store a street address

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to map specific street addresses. I know how to get the lat/lng coordinates *given* a street address:

```
geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
```

But what I don't know how to do is to store the address in the first place! Say that I have the address "123 Anystreet, Houston TX 77001". I have no idea how to store this in such a way that I can pass it to the geocoder. It's not a simple string, but what is it?

Sorry that I have no actual code to show, but that's exactly the problem. I've searched all around, but I don't see how to do this. Also sorry if this turns out to be a really obvious question. It seems like it should be, but I don't know the answer. Right now I'm only concerned with U.S. addresses.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually you post an answer to your own question as an answer and accept it. This way you notify everybody, you got it to work. I think your question was not clear enough to receive answers.

Comment: Thanks. I made that change. Not sure what was unclear about my question, though.

Comment: `"store the address"` was suggesting you want to store this: "123 Anystreet, Houston TX 77001". And you didn't say where you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work and thought that I would post my solution. If there is a better one, feel free to post.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> addresses;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    Location loc = new Location(provider);
    loc.setLatitude(address.getLatitude());
    loc.setLongitude(address.getLongitude());

    if (loc != null) {
        onLocationChanged(loc);
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```